# Parse Date and Time - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to parse the date and time as a number.

Any help would be great

```
Date.parse(11 + " " + 25 + ", " + 2016)
```

Would return `1480032000000`

How would I incorporate time into this?

I've tried something along the lines of `Date.parse(2 + " " + 2 + ", " + 2016 + " " + 09:00:00 GMT)` but it doesn't work.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: `1480032000000` is what they call epoch or unix timestamp in milliseconds. It is the amount of milliseconds since 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC or NaN if the string is unrecognised or, in some cases, contains illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31).

**Pulled from the mozilla documentation:**

```
Date.parse('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00 GMT');
```

Returns 807926400000 no matter the local time zone as GMT (UTC) is provided.

```
Date.parse('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00');
```

Returns 807937200000 in time zone GMT-0300, and other values in other time zones, since there is no time zone specifier in the argument and it is not ISO format, so is treated as local.

```
Date.parse('Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
```

Returns 0 no matter the local time zone as a time zone GMT (UTC) is provided.

```
Date.parse('Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00');
```

Returns 14400000 in time zone GMT-0400, and other values in other time zones, since no time zone is provided and the string is not in ISO format, therefore the local time zone is used.

```
Date.parse('Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT-0400');
```

Returns 14400000 no matter the local time zone as a time zone GMT (UTC) is provided.

```
Date.parse('11/25/2016 00:00:00 GMT');
```

returns:

```
1480032000000
```

Find the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this as the following statement

```
Date.parse(Date(11,25,2016,09,00,00));
```

Comment: That is the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're understanding wrong. Date.parse returns the milliseconds from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 until the date you specify. If you wanted to turn a string into a date you would need to use:

```
new Date('2011-04-11')
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
console.log(Date.parse(new Date("2/2/2016 09:00:00 GMT")))
console.log("adding 1 second to verify time is included.")
console.log(Date.parse(new Date("2/2/2016 09:00:01 GMT")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
Date.parse('02 Jan 1970 00:00:00')
```

You can mention HH:MM:ss

```
var d1 = Date.parse('02 Jan 1970 00:00:00')
var d2 = Date.parse('02 Jan 1970 01:02:03')
```

In the above example,
`d1 = 46800000`
`d2 = 50523000`

Answer (score -1):

```
Date.parse('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00 GMT');
```

Returns 807926400000 no matter the local time zone as GMT (UTC) is provided.

```
Date.parse('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00');
```

Returns 807937200000 in time zone GMT-0300, and other values in other time zones, since there is no time zone specifier in the argument and it is not ISO format, so is treated as local.

Look here for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse